# Sync to physics change in godot 4

Tags: game-engine, game-development, godot

I am in the process of converting my game from godot 3 to godot 4.

Previously in godot 3 when I was using rotating platforms, my player would sink a few pixels into the rotating platforms while they were moving up, and hover a few pixels above when the platforms were moving down. I fixed this by turning on sync to physics on the moving platform(s).

Now the problem is back, and there is no sync to physics option.

I was just wondering if this was an easy fix? Or should I redo the moving platform system entirely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended `Node` for moving platforms in Godot 3.x was `KinematicBody` (`2D`) with `motion/sync_to_physics` set to `true`.

As you know, `KinematicBody` (`2D`) became `CharacterBody` (`2D`/`3D`) in Godot 4. However, it is no longer recommended for moving platforms. Instead the recommended `Node` for moving platforms is `AnimatableBody` (`2D`/`3D`) which has a `sync_to_physics` property which does what you want.

Thus, your fix is to change the type of the node to `AnimatableBody` (`2D`/`3D`) and make sure the `sync_to_physics` property is set to `true` (which is the default).

*And yes, an `AnimatableBody` (`2D`/`3D`) is an `StaticBody` (`2D`/`3D`). I assure you it makes sense form the standpoint of the engine design, and also that it was a subject of endless debate (in particular if `StaticBody` (`2D`/`3D`) should still be called "static" if they sometimes are intended to move). But we failed to agree on something better. Please take it for what it is.*